# Validación en nest.js usando body y files

Tags: validación, nestjs

En nestjs como podría hacer una validación que use el body y los files de la solicitud.
En la que la propiedad "message" sea obligatoria solo cuando no se hallan enviado archivos, si hay archivos es opcional pero igualmente se valide que es string, intente usando validateIf pero como el dto es para el body no se tiene acceso a files

```
import { IsString, MinLength } from "class-validator";

export class SendMessageDto {
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(1)
    message:string
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(1)
    channel:string
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(1)
    server:string
}

import { Body, Controller, Get, Post, UploadedFiles, UseInterceptors } from "@nestjs/common";
import { FilesInterceptor } from "@nestjs/platform-express";

  @Post('/sendMessage')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
  create(@Body() data: SendMessageDto,@UploadedFiles() files: Express.Multer.File[]) {
    this.command.send(data,files)
   
  }
```

Probé usando un interceptor y funciono pero no se si es la mejor manera.
message en SendMessageDto  tiene @String, no se si al extender se propagen los decoradores de validación bien

```
export class SendMessageFilesDto extends SendMessageDto {
    @ValidateIf(dto => {
        return dto.files.length == 0
    })
    @MinLength(1)
    message: string
}

@Injectable()
export class FileWhithMessageInteceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    console.log('Before...');

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    
    if (request.body) {


      const dtoClass = plainToInstance(SendMessageFilesDto, {...request.body,files:request.files});
      const errors = await validate(dtoClass);
      const messageErrors = errors.map(error => Object.values(error.constraints)).flat()


      if (errors.length > 0) {
        throw new BadRequestException({
          statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
          message: messageErrors,
          error: "Bad Request"
      });
      }
    }

    return next
      .handle()

  }
}
```